# Hiding names from export list in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a small package in Python with the following module structure

```
package/
  __init__.py
  cls1.py
  cls2.py
  cls3.py
  mod1.py
  mod2.py
```

Where each `clsN.py` has a single class `ClsN` in it, and each `modN.py` contains various functions using those classes.  I would like my import structure to look like

```
package
package.Cls1
package.Cls2
package.Cls3
package.mod1
package.mod1.func1
...
package.mod2
package.mod2.func2
...
```

without polluting the namespace.  Right now I have the problem that I can access any of these classes through `package.Cls1` and `package.cls1.Cls1`, and I can also access everything defined in `package/cls1.py` (including imports).  I've tried setting the `__all__` variable, but that appears to do nothing except during `from package import *`.  Is there a way to keep Python from showing `clsN` as submodules?  Or even just a way to hide imports inside those files?  I don't want the users of my library to have two ways of getting to each class.

Comment: You can do a variety of tricks, but usually the simplest answer is the same as with other private attributes (like methods): just prefix the private modules with a `_`, which should be enough to discourage people from using them.

Comment: @abarnert I've thought of that, but I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible.  This is a library that will be reviewed by people who don't necessarily know Python well (the problem with using multiple languages in the workplace), and I know I'll get told to remove the underscore because it looks weird.

However, if this is generally considered the "pythonic" way of doing things, I can use that as a strong enough argument.

EDIT: Because I didn't hit shift+enter

Comment: And now that I've posted it, I find that my answer is essentially identical to @abarnert's comment. I do think my intro paragraph is important though: Don't worry about visibility issues, just document the "correct" location of your objects and let your users do what they want!

Comment: @bheklilr: Complaints about the underscores would be like someone from a Python background telling a C programmer to get rid of all those semicolons because they look weird. Why can't you just tell them "no, that's standard practice"?

Comment: Well, it looks weird on purpose—the whole point is to "scare people away from using it", right? Besides, if someone is trying to apply Python-unfriendly requirements on your Python code, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: @Blckknght: Agreed; the key is to make the right way to do things the obvious way to do things, not to try to make it the _only_ way.

Comment: @Blckknght: While I agree with you that it should just be how it is and the user should RTFM, some of my users are not very well versed with programming, let alone Python, and I was really wanting to restrict it to one way to save time and effort down the road.  The reason why my users are not experienced is not important, just accept that some of these people don't know the difference between a class and an object.

Comment: @bheklilr: If they ask why they have to use those weird underscore names, just tell them: "You don't. The weird underscore names are there to scare you away. You never need to use them, anywhere."

Comment: @abarnert: I'll have to run it by my manager before I refactor the project.  If he lets me do it, then it will be that way, but if he says "no", then there's no chance it'll make it passed the rest of the team.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stdlib has two ways of dealing with cases like this.

The first is simple: Just mark the private modules private in the same way you mark any other attributes private: with an underscore prefix. This doesn't hide them from users, but it does signify that users shouldn't use them (and may prevent things like iPython or PyDev from offering them as completions), and that's usually good enough.

The only real problem with this is that underscore prefixes on module names also tend to imply that they're native accelerators—in other words, a user might expect that `_foo` is implemented by `foomodule.c` rather than `_foo.py`.

Another alternative is to either not import them—use `from submodule import name, other, yetanother`—or to `del` them at the end of your module. The fact that you explicitly want `package.Cls1` to be the same type as `package.cls1.Cls1`, etc. implies that this is exactly what you want.

The user can still *explicitly* import them if they want. But Python doesn't generally give you any way to block malice or intentional stupidity, and you shouldn't try.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I suggest not worrying too much about what is visible from where. If a user tries to access `package.mod1.Cls1`, is it really a problem if it works? Python is generally a pretty permissive language, and trying to hide stuff is often more trouble than it's worth.

That said, if you want to make non-standard access a bit less likely, a good way is to import your classes into your modules with alternative names, starting with underscores. Variables with single underscores at the start of their names are not imported with `from _ import *` nor do they show up in a `dir` listing. Here's how you could do that:

In `mod1.py`:

```
from .Cls1 import Cls1 as _Cls1
from .Cls2 import Cls2 as _Cls2
from .Cls3 import Cls3 as _Cls3
```

Then just use the underscore names in your module's code. Other code that wants to get at the classes will probably go find them under their "official" location.